# xcode 4.6 to commit source code to the TFS

Tags: ios, tf-cli

I got a problem while using xcode 4.6 to commit source code to the TFS, i'm using [git-tf](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/use-git-and-xcode-with-tfs/)
but i can't commit source to server. I have been cloned folder from server. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have cloned your code on TFS to local git repo you are ready to make changes. Once you do them use:

```
git commit -a -m "commnent"
```

Now you can check them in your TFS:

```
git tf checkin
```

All commits will be checked as one single changeset on TFS.